# Spring Tools Suite: Download : Link is not working

Tags: spring-tool-suite

Can you please advise how to resolve the download issue with Spring tools suite. I am trying to download from the site: http://spring.io/tools/sts/all

and it does not show the active link to download.  Please help.

Thank you
Regards
Radha

Comment: STS download links are working perfectly fine. Here are the direct download links for [Windows 32Bit](http://download.springsource.com/release/STS/3.6.3/dist/e4.4/spring-tool-suite-3.6.3.RELEASE-e4.4.1-win32-x86_64.zip) and [Windows 64Bit](http://download.springsource.com/release/STS/3.6.3/dist/e4.4/spring-tool-suite-3.6.3.RELEASE-e4.4.1-win32-x86_64.zip)

Comment: and if you are looking for linux version, here it goes
[Linux 32Bit](http://download.springsource.com/release/STS/3.6.3/dist/e4.4/spring-tool-suite-3.6.3.RELEASE-e4.4.1-linux-gtk.tar.gz) and [Linux 64 Bit](http://download.springsource.com/release/STS/3.6.3/dist/e4.4/spring-tool-suite-3.6.3.RELEASE-e4.4.1-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz)

Answer (score 0):

you have to click on the little three-horizontal-lines icon on the right side of each download area to open the popup that contains the download links. (If the popup doesn't show up, I would recommend to try a different browser.)

Hope that helps!!!